# SVG Lines Between Grid Boxes

Tags: css

I'm trying to add an animated SVG line in between my grid boxes, sort of [like this example](https://codepen.io/borntofrappe/pen/ZMJjQL), but horizontally.

I'm running into two issues that, after all my reading, I'm still unable to solve:

1: How might you align the SVG line to the middle of the other boxes?
2: I'd love for the dots to be animated like in the example above, but borrowing that code and applying it to the line doesn't seem to have any affect.

```
svg {
    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

svg>line {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 1px 10px;
    animation: animateline 5s linear both infinite;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 0;
}

.box {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <svg>
        <line x1="0" x2="500" y1="10" y2="10" />
    </svg>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>
    <svg>
        <line x1="0" x2="500" y1="10" y2="10" />
    </svg>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Box 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier idea that rely on gradient and animation of background-position. You should, by the way, add background to the box element to hide the non need part of the background:

```css
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: calc(100%/5) calc(100%/5) calc(100%/5);
    grid-gap: calc(100%/5);
    background:radial-gradient(8px 4px at center,#000 50%,transparent 50%) 0 50%/16px 200px;
    animation:change 3s linear infinite;
}

.box {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background:#fff;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-position:0 50%;
  }
  to {
    background-position:32px 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <p>Box 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In case you need transparency and you will only have 3 boxes you can consider pseuo element like below:

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(100%/5) calc(100%/5) calc(100%/5);
  grid-gap: calc(100%/5);
  position:relative;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100%/5);
  background: 
   radial-gradient(8px 4px at center, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 0 50%/16px 200px;
  animation: change 3s linear infinite;
}
.container::before {
  left:calc(100%/5);
}
.container::after {
  right:calc(100%/5);
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
body {
  background:pink;
}
@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 32px 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Box 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Box 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p>Box 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oooh me likey. Thanks!

Comment: @DD1229 I have made an update in case you want a transparent solution

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to flip the line so it's vertical? From what I'm gathering, we're leveraging the entire background and the boxes are just laid on top of it. For example, let's say I wanted to "draw" a vertical line between two containers.

Edit: I'm trying to anticipate what this would look like being "responsive."

Comment: @DD1229 you simply need to flip all the values ;) here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/w5nyLqrh/ .. compare with the code here and you will see that I simply switched values (including the ones defined in the animation)

Comment: I decided to ditch the grid and just do a vertical layout. I flipped this little connector line using a spacer, but the animation jumps just ever so slightly. I played with every value in there that I can think of, but I can't get rid of it. Thoughts? https://jsfiddle.net/n5z7pabu/

Comment: @DD1229 as you can see you used `18px` value to define the size so the value in the position should be a multiplier of it, actually you used `75px` but you should use `18px` or `36px` or `72px` ,etc